# Label showing wrong values while NSLog shows the right ones in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit, string-formatting, sklabelnode

Label not showing the required values but `nslog` shows the right values that should be shown by the label. The label show a big number that is full of digits. Have I done anything wrong?, the relevant code shown below.

How it looks at the top...

```
@implementation ORPlayerResults
{ 
    SKLabelNode *numberOfPointsLabel;

    NSInteger newPoints;
    NSString *addingNewPointNumberStored;
}
```

In `didMoveToView`...

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{    
    // adding the label
    [self addChild:[self pointsTotalLabel]];
}
```

Information about the label

```
-(SKLabelNode *)pointsTotalLabel
{
    numberOfPointsLabel = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
    numberOfPointsLabel.text = @"Points Achieved: 0";
    numberOfPointsLabel.fontSize = 35;
    numberOfPointsLabel.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    numberOfPointsLabel.position = CGPointMake((self.size.width * 0.5)-200, self.size.height - 200);
    numberOfPointsLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;

    return numberOfPointsLabel;
}
```

the text label below is not showing the right values, but rather showing a wrong big number full of digits. `nslog` shows the results that I want.

```
-(void)pointsAchieved
{
    newPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kORNewPoints];
    addingNewPointNumberStored = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)newPoints];
    numberOfPointsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points Achieved: %ld", (long)addingNewPointNumberStored];

    NSLog(@"Points accumulated is: %@", addingNewPointNumberStored);
}
```

Comment: I think using dispatch_get_main_queue() may solve this.

Comment: @Roecrew how will the code look like? I have never used  dispatch_get_main_queue().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember the name of them but you've mixed up your %@, %ld thingies.

Your NSLog uses %@ and works.

Your label.text uses %ld and does not.

You put your number in a string and then added that string to the label.text as if it were still a number.
So you also need to remove the (long) from that statement.

Answer (score 1):

You got confused on the different types in the formatting string, it should look like this:

```
-(void)pointsAchieved
{
newPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kORNewPoints];
addingNewPointNumberStored = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newPoints];
numberOfPointsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points Achieved: %@", addingNewPointNumberStored];

NSLog(@"Points accumulated is: %@", addingNewPointNumberStored);
}
```